# .change() doesn't fire oninput

Tags: jquery

How could I fire `.on('input')` programmatically in jQuery?
`.change()` or `.trigger('change')` don't seem too work.

Here's a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/4o3v2c6s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `trigger('input')` instead of the `change()` shorthand.

```js
$(".val-trigger").on('input', function() {
  console.log("this is triggered on input! :)");
});

$(".val-trigger").change(function() {
  console.log("triggered!");
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      $("#example").val("test").trigger('input'); // < change here
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="val-trigger">
  <input type="text" id="example" />
</div>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4o3v2c6s/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try updated fiddle [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/4o3v2c6s/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/4o3v2c6s/2/)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      $("#example").val("test").change();
      $("#example").val("test").trigger('input');
  });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give the function a name and call it whenever you like:

```
function doAThing() {
   alert("triggered!");
}

// Auto:
$(".val-trigger").change(doAThing);

// Manual:
doAThing();
```